# Getting java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 7: http:/${Bearer}

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have an API name loginUser, which generates the authorization Token, that is to be passed in other subsequent APIs.

**Below is the response:-**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 10 Nov 2018 07:08:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 71
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: date, authorization, x-powered-by, connection, server, access-control-allow-origin, content-type, content-length, x-final-url
authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIyYmEyYjc1My03NWEwLTQxNGYtYWFiOC0zZGY1M2I4YmIwMDEiLCJpc0Nvb2siOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTU0MTgzMzcyNX0.3FRVpHm4EF2Ahzzy-OjbZ2EeZto6-hSFKHNtG5wcjBs

Where I want to fetch the authorization.

I'm using Regular Expression Extractor, but it is throwing below error (URISyntaxException: illegal character in the path)

Snapshots:-

[Step_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRgTT.png)

[image: Step_2]

[image: Step_3]

[Step_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YItav.png)

I have seen couple of queries related to this Error but not in Jmeter,
And i tried using % also, to get rid out of this error, but that didn't work out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization is sent/receive in headers,

Change Step 2, Field to check should be Response Headers to get the value

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after changing that i am getting below error in View Results Tree.

Comment: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: http:/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIyYmEyYjc1My03NWEwLTQxNGYtYWFiOC0zZGY1M2I4YmIwMDEiLCJpc0Nvb2siOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTU0MTg1ODc4NX0.KgwnC9UoYifFuBZO7opjKH2pQfM4k-_N_8McsUyRtMI
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:95)

Comment: @shank Step 3 you might be to pass Bearer in HTTP Header of the request instead of its path

Comment: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: eyjhbgcioijiuzi1niisinr5cci6ikpxvcj9.eyj1c2vyswqioiiyymeyyjc1my03nwewltqxngytywfioc0zzgy1m2i4ymiwmdeilcjpc0nvb2sionrydwusimlhdci6mtu0mtg2njk4nn0.182foo90hnmmbsdwjqxdo7_zwuefpnqzg0vlyfmgbom
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:421)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:310)

Comment: @shank please ask a new question with how you supposed to send autorization and what you tried and failed with error